# Можно-ли кодируя программу в 32-бита использовать 64-битные регистры? И если да то как это происходит. Если что то FASM

Tags: ассемблер

Прописываю к примеру use32 ,а использую регистры R(64-битные).Что будет?Если что то FASM.

Comment: Ну так а почему бы не попробовать? Сообщите о результатах.

Comment: Попробуй, думаю заругается.

Comment: В принципе TigerTV.ru был прав.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

нет, но можно использовать 32-битные регистры в 64-битной программе.
не трать время на 32 бита, учись сразу на 64.

Comment: "Не трать время на ассемблер, не гонись за тактами, учи теорию алгоритмов", сказал бы я 16-летнему себе, на что бы получил ответ: "Чего бы ты понимал, тупой старпёр".

Comment: Вы были правы ,компилятор его просто "не переварил".А наоборот 64 бит с 32-битными регистрами как милый запустил.

Comment: @extm алгоритмы на ассемблере гораздо интересней просто алгоритмов